# Player's Bumpy Movement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When my player jumps and lands on something it always shakes around [like that.](https://gyazo.com/f5b986501db13743fd3ae7b6a8c3e048)
Also, sometimes when I jump a few times in a row (about 10 times) it would go through the ground and just fall down.
I tried using a collider and I don't see anything in the movement script that may cause this. I'm currently using Unity 2018.4.20f1 and Visual Studio c#.
Any solutions?

Player Movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int movespeed = 6;
    public Vector3 userDirection = Vector3.right;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public bool isGrounded;

    Vector3 jumpMovement;

    bool jump = false;

    [SerializeField]
    float jumpHeight = 1.8f, jumpSpeed = 8f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    }


    void OnCollisionStay()
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }

    public float fallMultiplier = 3.5f;
    public float lowJumpMultiplier = 2f;


    void Update()
    {
        //movement
        transform.Translate(userDirection * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && !jump)
            StartCoroutine(Jump());
    }


    IEnumerator Jump()
    {
        float originalHeight = transform.position.y;
        float maxHeight = originalHeight + jumpHeight;
        jump = true;
        yield return null;

        while (transform.position.y < maxHeight)
        {
            transform.position += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * jumpSpeed;
            yield return null;
        }

        while (transform.position.y > originalHeight)
        {
            transform.position -= transform.up * Time.deltaTime * jumpSpeed;
            yield return null;
        }

        rb.useGravity = true;
        jump = false;

        yield return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try disabling bounciness for your rigidbody via a physicsMaterial (in case it's indeed rigidbody bouncing, which it may not be)?

Comment: Just made a new material with 0 bounciness to try it out, still shakey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I didn't notice the link.

You are forcing it to go down to `originalHeight`, without checking if there is an object higher than that. You can remove

```
while (transform.position.y > originalHeight)
{
    transform.position -= transform.up * Time.deltaTime * jumpSpeed;
    yield return null;
}
```

and let the rigidbody control gravity (by setting `rb.useGravity = true;` as you did).

Original answer:

You are probably going below the ground when calling `transform.position -= transform.up * Time.deltaTime * jumpSpeed;`. Try adding

```
if (transform.position.y < originalHeight)
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, originalHeight, transform.position.z)
```

after it.